# Function augmentation in .Net?

Tags: c#, function

During .Net interview, I was asked what is function augmentation. Never heard it and couldn't find anything related.

Any ideas what that is in .Net?

AJ

Comment: Are you sure you didn't mishear?

Comment: The only thing I can imagine might be close to what they wanted is AOP (Aspect Oriented Programming)... Aside from that it is probably one of the questions where the interviewer is trying to prove how smart HE is :p

Comment: Or study your response to a question you cannot possibly know the correct answer to.  Simply saying you don't know would have been the best response.

Comment: I asked him twice to confirm. I guess it may be something related to functional language like F#. just guessing..

Comment: @nobugz - that's what I said that I have missed that term.

Comment: Could possibly have referred to extension methods. If the interviewer couldn't or didn't explain what it was, that is a big signal as to the type of person he/she is.  Josh hit it on the head.

Comment: The fact that this post is currently the #1 hit for a google search for "function augmentation", and that all other 9 hits on the first page are non-programming and non-IT related, hints at the fact that either this was a trick question, or the interviewer misunderstands something himself (e.g. he read something similar in some "pattern" book a long time ago and forgot half ot it), but wanted to show off. The latter happens a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is partial methods.

-- Edit:

Though it's worth noting, it's not a familiar term in the .NET world.

Answer (score 2):

They probably were referring to [extension methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx)?

Comment: Whatever "function augmentation" is (and I'm not claiming to know), the English interpretation of the phrase is enhancing functions. I would consider extension methods and enhancement of types, not of functions.

Answer (score 1):

maybe it is just [Fluent Interface](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface) and he wanted to you infer what he mean

Answer (score 0):

I'm just throwing this out wildly, but I bet he meant "how do you write a method that accepts a lambda function as its argument?"

In other words, he was looking for the use of the [Func<>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549151.aspx) delegates.